# Centos 7 Node.js не запускается приложение

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

Такой вопросик встал перед мной, значит разрабатывал я приложение на node.js на винде, на которой оно собственно и работало, но пришел тот момент, когда тестирование приложения закончилось и пора уже поставить приложение на простенький vps на Centos 7 по инструкциям я смог установить node, но вот проблема в том что приложение там не запускается. Просто ничего, запускаю приложение и снова коммандная строка Putty и ничего не выводится и не выполняется. Может кто-то знает в чем проблема?

PS. ошибок нету, пакеты установлены

Предположительная часть кода которая не работает:

```
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');

const logOnOptions = {
   accountName: config.username, // Имя аккаунта
   password: config.password, // Пароль от аккаунта
   twoFactorCode: SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(config.sharedSecret) // ключ с помощью которого генерируется так называемый Steam Guard Code
};
client.logOn(logOnOptions); // Функция которая осуществлюяет вход
```

Comment: Ну так бери его и дебажь console.log'ами.

Comment: Так в том то и прикол, что там везде console.log'и, я то по этому и сюда обратился)

Comment: Значит не везде. Просто файл из одной строки `console.log(123)` работает?

Comment: Да, это работает, я создавал бота для steam. Библиотеки от DoctorMcKay.

Comment: Ну так давай минимальный пример кода, который не работает.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я конкретно не знаю какая часть кода не работает корректно на linux, но судя по тому, что я вычитал про ошибку, которая начала вылазить после многократной попытки запуска когда, это то, что код не может войти в аккаунт. Приложу кусок кода.

Comment: Изменил тело вопроса, тк не знаю куда можно было еще добавить часть кода)

Comment: Какая версия nodejs?

Comment: Разобрался, на сервере было указано время, в следствии чего и код генерировался не верно)